# Where is the Ext JS 4 ux package

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs

I'm learning ExtJS 4 and I just figured out how to center containers/panels. In order to do this I needed to add the following at the top of my my app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'extjs/examples/ux');
Ext.require('Ext.ux.layout.Center');
```

The ux folder is in the example folder that came with ExtJS 4, I'm wondering why this package and some others are in the examples folder rather than being in the src folder with the rest of the framework.

Comment: I, too, find this odd.

Answer (score 7):

Because Sencha considers them being "beta-code". Often code what was in `ux` will be included into main code branch in the following releases.

Comment: to add clarification: "ux" stands for User Extensions, meaning not built by Sencha necessarily and therefore not part of the framework out of the box.

Comment: So they include documentation for beta stuff as part of the framework?  That seems a bit ... odd.